# How to compute expressions like ~0x000C by hand?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm student of electrical engineering. At our programming class we were given bunch of exercises for C language and asked to explain what happens and how your IDE performs bit operations.

So, for example if I'm given `unsigned short x = 0x000C` and perform `~x`, the output is `65523`. How does your IDE perform this operation?

Comment: IDE is not performing these operations. Anyway, have you heard about binary representation of numbers?

Comment: I understand how numbers are represented in binary notation.

Comment: You need to learn about hex, binary and decimal representations of numbers and how to convert between them.

Comment: Then convert to binary by hand, perform the operation and convert back to whatever you want. Done.

Comment: So essentially you convert into whatever you want, then perform the operation (NOT, OR, AND, XOR, XNOR) and then convert back into desirable notation?

Comment: Yes. Unless you have enough experience with this stuff to skip the intermediate steps.

Comment: The value of `~x` is very unlikely to be 65523 unless you're assigning it back to a variable of type `unsigned short`. The other explanation is that on your C implementation short and int have the same size, but that's extremely uncommon.

Comment: `unsigned short x=0x000c; printf("%d", ~x);` will output -13 in most implementations of C, and not 65523. That's because `~x` actually means something like `~int(x)` because of the usual arithmetic conversions. So your IDE is doing something weird if it tells you that ~x is 65523.

Answer (score 6):

To provide some context, generally speaking, we use the following prefixes to denote different base representations of numbers:

- No prefix means base-10, a.k.a. decimal (what we use in everyday life)
- `0x` means base-16, a.k.a. hexadecimal (count from 0-9A-F, so a single digit can represent any value between 0 and 15...this requires four bits because the number 15 has a decimal representation of `0b1111`)
- `0b` means base-2, a.k.a. binary (count from 0-1...requires 1 bit per digit)
- `0` means base-8, a.k.a. octal (count from 0-7...requires 3 bits per digit)

So, given that, which you likely already knew but another user may not, this is what is happening behind the scenes in a very high-level way. Assuming an `unsigned short` is 16 bits wide in your environment, and given...

`unsigned short x = 0x000C = 0b0000 0000 0000 1100`

...a `~` is a bitwise negation operator, which means you just flip all the bits. So, for example:

`~0b0000 0000 0000 1100 = 0b1111 1111 1111 0011 = 0xFFF3 = 65523`

As a note, things like this get tricky when you start trying to do them in languages (like Python and VBScript) that abstract native types like integers into "infinitely large numbers". Flipping the bits of a 16-bit unsigned short is a lot different, and more possible, than flipping the bits of an "infinitely large number".

Comment: @PeroWhatshisnamović absolutely! Glad that helps. Just remember that the ALU is dealing with the binary representation of numbers. All other representations are abstractions by our programming languages to make our lives easier...once compiled and assembled down into machine code, it's all binary. Thus, it helps to think about all of these bitwise operations and their operands in binary terms.

Comment: @Treebasher - except for machines that use BCD representations :-)

Comment: @pm100 truth. And network protocols and such. God help them :P. But even at the lowest level, BCD representations are still just bits...you just have to know how you are scaling and masking them.

Comment: Note that `0b` is not a standard C prefix, though it is in C++14 and beyond so many C compilers support it as an extension.